# How to run scenebuilder from gluon on linux?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, gluon

I downloaded [scenebuilder-10.0.0-all.jar](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) on my computer and tried to launch it:

**case 1)**

```
$ java -jar scenebuilder-10.0.0-all.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

**case2)**

```
$ chmod +x ./scenebuilder-10.0.0-all.jar
$ ./scenebuilder-10.0.0-all.jar
./scenebuilder-10.0.0-all.jar: line 1: $'PK\003\004': command not found
./scenebuilder-10.0.0-all.jar: line 2: $'\b\b\200h\305L\002': command not found
./scenebuilder-10.0.0-all.jar: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\320\v\006''
K-*▒▒ϳR0▒3▒▒▒M▒▒▒u▒I,.▒RH▒▒▒▒/JL▒I▒▒J,KL▒▒+NN▒KM*▒▒II-▒K,(▒NIFEST.MF▒M▒▒LK-.▒
```

**java**: 11

```
$ java -version
java version "11.0.2" 2018-10-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+7-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+7-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why don't you try Scene Builder 11 (rc) for Linux? SB10 won't work on Java 11.

Comment: Thanks, I will try tomorrow. I have not tried as it is not a stable release.